# If I just change the lyrics and flow (very slightly) of a song is it called a cover or a remix?

Tags: songwriting, lyrics, rap

Is it referred as to something else? Like my version of a song or tribute.

Answer (score 6):

If you play and sing it yourself, then it's a cover. If you merely use editing tools to change it around, then it's a remix. A remix generally doesn't include a new performance or recording, it's merely editing and changing what has already been recorded.

A cover is a new recording or performance of a song written by someone else, or sometimes it's a new recording or performance of a song originally performed and/or recorded by someone else, regardless of who wrote it.

A tribute song is an original song, likely in the style of the band or artist that it is a tribute of. A tribute band is a band that performs and/or records several covers all originally written/performed/recorded by the same band. Tribute bands usually also dress up like the bands they are tributes of, and may even replicate stage elements, etc.

---

Note that covers and remixes require a license from the copyright holder or else they are usually infringing on that copyright. For a live performance of a cover or remix, smaller venues often pay a blanket licensing fee. For larger venues, the act performing the cover (you, in this case) may have to pay the fee directly. Copyright holders can refuse to license their songs for public performance (if I'm not mistaken), but cannot refuse to license their songs for recording. This is called "compulsory licensing", which means you must be allowed to record the song, but the copyright holder can charge you a reasonable fee to do so. I am not a lawyer. Consult a licensed attorney before doing anything with legal ramifications.

Comment: Ah I see so since this is rap and I'm not performing just recording I would assume this is a remix then correct?

Comment: @Kite What are you recording? If you're recording yourself rapping, then that's a cover. The recording is of a performance, even if it's not a public performance.

Comment: @Kite As my second paragraph says, if you record new material, especially if you record a new vocal track, then it's a cover.

Comment: Yes the only changes to the song Is my voice and few different lyrics everything else is the same. As for the copyright I don't plan to release this in any form it's more for experimentation to keep to myself I was just wondering whether it was called a remix or cover.

Comment: @Kite Yes, that's a cover.

Comment: You might add a note about satire/parody:  if you make significant changes to the lyrics with humorous intent, you are exempt from all copyright law.  Because it's parody, use of the original tune is allowed.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I’m not personally aware of that being the case so I’m not going to assert it. I understand that in the past, whether something is parody has often been decided in the courts, since the law is not precise on that matter, and even going to court is expensive. So generally I would prefer to get permission/license for any use of another’s work.